# Git ignore is ignoring some of the wrong files

Tags: git, gitignore

I have the following `.gitignore` file, and whenever I do `git add .` only the `.gitignore` file gets added to the repo, what is wrong with my ignore file?

Here is the file:

```
# Ignore Everything
*

# Except for these:
!.gitignore
!Assets/
!ProjectSettings/
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The wildcard without a leading slash is excluding everything within all directories.

Here's the sample code that the gitignore documentation suggests (modified for your case)

```
# exclude everything 
/*
!/Assets
!/ProjectSettings
```

Here's the documentation site: http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore